# Investigate who blocked local admin from running mmc

Tags: administration

The local admin was recently blocked from running mmc.exe. UAC message says 'An administrator has blocked you from running this app.' I'm looking for details on how to investigate this. I'm not sure what event logs to check. Advanced Auditing is configured so the logs could be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is probably a hint that a domain administrator has added a group policy. That means that the modification was loaded on your local machine by the system when it loads the group policies from the network.

I am afraid that you would have to look at the domain logs to know more.

Comment: There are unexpected AD programs on this workstation. Is it possible that Azure AD is part of the Windows Insider Developers edition? The registry has some enabled keys referencing AD. Does Windows Insider ever take over system permissions?